# How to Center my Nav bar, and put the social media icons on the side

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/qnw7a9zk/

I'm attempting to put the nav bar in the center, and the social media icons on the side. I've looked up other solutions to this problem, but none also want to put the icons on the side.

If I try to float the nav bar to the left, and the icons to the right, it kind of works, but the nav bar isn't in the center, and if I were to change the size of the window (responsiveness) the bar kind of breaks.

I can only get the icons to the right, but not on the same row as the nav bar, and they are stuck below it.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="logo" src="Logo.png" />
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="navlist"><a href="#">Properties</a></li>
      <li class="navlist"><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
      <li class="navlist"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="imgs">
      <a href="#" title="Twitter" alt=" Icon"><img src="Instagram.png" /></a>
      <a href="#" title="Twitter" alt=" Icon"><img src="Facebook.png" /></a>
      <a href="#" title="Twitter" alt=" Icon"><img src="Twitter.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<footer>
  <p class="buttons">Real estate</p>
</footer>
</body>


body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(nice.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  background-color: #cbb492;
  display: table-row;
  height: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: black;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #cbb492;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.logo {
  height: 28px;
  width: 90px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.navlist {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 2.4px;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0px;
}

.imgs {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0px;
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
}

.imgs img {
  width: 9%;
  height: 9%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to move the .imgs-div one level higher. Than it should be easier. One approach could be the flexbox model. So the wrapper-container gets

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
```

I just did some more edits. Is this what you wanted to achive?
https://jsfiddle.net/qnw7a9zk/6/

Comment: I've never read about display:flex or flex direction, is this new with HTML 5?

Comment: It is a CSS3 layout method (I personally really like).

Comment: Could you also explain to me why the .imgs div is much bigger than the actual images contained within them?

Comment: I actually added a ´width: 80px;` which you could/should remove. Than the .imgs div is as big as the images.

Comment: #edit: I just saw that it isn't if the .imgs img height and width are set as percentage. If you set it absolute as px it is ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have given `width:100%` to `.nav` so it is taking full width and pushes images down. Keep the width ratio maintained in navigation and image. Like `80%` navidation and `20 %` images, see fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/qnw7a9zk/5/

Answer (score 0):

You may do it by `display: inline-block`

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(nice.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  background-color: #cbb492;
  display: table-row;
  height: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: black;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #cbb492;
}

nav {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center
}

.logo {
  height: 28px;
  width: 90px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.navlist {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 2.4px;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.imgs {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="navlist"><a href="#">Properties</a></li>
      <li class="navlist"><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
      <li class="navlist"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="imgs">
      <a href="#" title="Twitter" alt=" Icon"><img src="Instagram.png" /></a>
      <a href="#" title="Twitter" alt=" Icon"><img src="Facebook.png" /></a>
      <a href="#" title="Twitter" alt=" Icon"><img src="Twitter.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <img class="logo" src="Logo.png" />
</div>
<footer>
  <p class="buttons">Real estate</p>
</footer>
</body>
```